# images colliding together when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css

My problem is when I resize my browser my images collide together rather then staying in their own designated formation. Realistically when I resize my browser I would like my images to move with the browser but not collide with each other. Here is the code, thanks in advanced.

Here is my HTML...

```
<div id="header-images">

    <img src="images/title.png" id="header_title" class="animated bounceInLeft" alt="Title Header"></img>

    <img src="images/header_interface.png" id="interface" class="animated bounceInRight" alt="Poyan's Interface"></img>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS...

```
    #header_title {     
    width: 561px;   
    height: 248px;
    margin-top: 175px;
    left: 37.5%;
    margin-left: -280.5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1000;
    min-width: 100px;
}

    #interface {
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 338px;
    height: 315px;
    margin-top: 165px;
    left: 73%;
    margin-left: -169px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing your layout. http://jsfiddle.net/6PQy5/1/ You have a very convoluted layout there. What's with the crazy positions and margins? What's the overall goal?

Comment: I have given those css codes because they were working at the time, but until I resized my browser I noticed the problem. The goal is to have two images, one a title header and the second one a portrait photograph side by side. When my browser is at its maximum they are fine, but once I start resizing down they start colliding together.

Comment: And you still haven't told us what you'd rather have happen. They'll either need to stay adjacent to one another, running outside the page, or they'll need to wrap to two lines. Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css to fix images width so it keeps distance and not collide:

```
#header-images img {
    Width: 45%;
}
```

This will keep 10%distance between both images

Comment: Doing that stretches my images beyond their determined height and width.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where they wrap to two lines:

http://jsfiddle.net/6PQy5/3/

```
#header_title {
    width: 561px;
    height: 248px;
    margin-top: 175px;
    float: left;
}
#interface {
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 338px;
    height: 315px;
    margin-top: 165px;
    float: right;
}
```

Here's an example where they scroll offscreen:

http://jsfiddle.net/6PQy5/4/

```
#header_images {min-width: 920px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried doing both of these and they both run the image to the next line. I don't know how else I can explain this but the "header_title" is on the left of screen and the "interface" image is on the right, when I resize my browser from the left side the "interface" image goes on top of the other image. I want there to still be space between the two image when I resize my browser. I also have the option to keep both of these absolutely positioned without moving what so ever, but I don't think that would be user friendly, that is my fall back option though.

Comment: I figured it out, it was a super noob mistake, but I didn't set a container div for all my elements, that is why they were all out of whack! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Select an answer and/or upvote any that were helpful, please.